# Looping through ajaxcallback (WCF Service)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf

I am using a for loop through "task", which is json object response. In this loop I have called a function to SAVE "task" using ajaxcallback (WCF Service). But problem is Insertion/Updation the rows are affecting randomly in tables(SQL Server).

```
for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    para = {taskName: task.Name, tasktype:TaskType }
    SaveTask();
}

SaveTask()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "localhost/MyService/Task.svc/SaveTask",
        data: para,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //alert("Successfully Added task");
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
}
```

I think while service is running, the next iteration starts, so it executes randomly.
If any met with the same issue please response ASAP.

Thanks

Comment: *Insertion/Updation the rows are affecting randomly in tables* - this does not make sense. In what way are the inserts/updates random? Do you mean the order of the calls is random?

Comment: Yes, Exactly
The insertion order is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons why this may be happening, but most likely is you're suffering a race condition.

You're making a high number of calls to your service in a very short period of time, and even factoring out the network latency, the server is probably invoking multiple threads to service your multiple requests.

Each thread attempts to access the database at the same, with unpredictable results.